# Python dfply Package join data by two columns

Tags: python-3.x, dfply

I have a need to join 2 datasets by 2 columns. Seems like no functionality in 'dfply' package. Am I thikning right? please help

```
pat_active = (patients >>
         inner_join(active, by = ('StationID','PracticeID'))
        )
```

Documentation about library:
https://github.com/kieferk/dfply